# How to vertically space (margin-likely) a list of inline-block elements?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if this is even possible without modifying the HTML, but, say that you have a list of inline-block elements of a variable width that are dynamically added. You don't want any margin between the elements and the parent, but in case they start forming two lines, you'd like to have some space between them.
I've tried `::first-line` but it doesn't work for margins. So does anyone know how to do this?

Take this example:

```css
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #555;
  padding: 1px;
}
.parent p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #CCC;
}
.parent::first-line {
  margin-bottom: 10px;/* not working */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>sit amet,</p>
  <p>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Tempora,</p>
  <p>numquam, reiciendis.</p>
  <p>Voluptatum molestias,</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: No. because there is no CSS method for detecting line breakage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting a `margin-top` to the children and a `negative margin` to the parent. By this, it will pull the children to the top removing the space between them.

Bootstrap's `row` and `col-` works this way.

```css
.parent {
  margin: -18px 0;
  background: #555;
  padding: 1px;
}
.parent p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #CCC;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>sit amet,</p>
  <p>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Tempora,</p>
  <p>numquam, reiciendis.</p>
  <p>Voluptatum molestias,</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "parent" is a class defined for div, so you're trying to apply bottom margin to div, which is wrong,

The solution of this is you modify your code to this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .parent {
              margin: 20px;
              background: #555;
              padding: 1px;
            }
            .parent p {
              display: inline-block;
              margin: 0;
              margin-right: 5px;
              padding: 0;
              background: #CCC;
            }
            .parent p::first-line {            //Line modified by Dixit, added " p"
              margin-bottom: 10px;/* not working */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <p>sit amet,</p>
      <p>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Tempora,</p>
      <p>numquam, reiciendis.</p>
      <p>Voluptatum molestias,</p>
      <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
      <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
      <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
      <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**But still it will not work**, the reason is because you've already set the margin to 0, inside .parent p{} block, the way you can achieve it is by removing the margin:0; line from .parent p{} block which will result in following code.

```css
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #555;
  padding: 1px;
}
.parent p {
  display: inline-block;
  //Line removed by Dixit, Line : margin:0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #CCC;
}
.parent p::first-line {
  //Line modified by Dixit, added " p"
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* not working */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>sit amet,</p>
  <p>consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Tempora,</p>
  <p>numquam, reiciendis.</p>
  <p>Voluptatum molestias,</p>
  <p>sequi iste itaque corporis ducimus,</p>
  <p>vero commodi sed fugiat</p>
  <p>qui a perferendis sint,</p>
  <p>magnam doloribus quidem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Fine but I splicitly mentioned there must not be a separation between the parent and the first and last child... I had come already to that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the given script to know the top positions of first and last element of P, and and can remove the top margin for Ps in first row, and can remove bottom margin for Ps in last row.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("p").each(function( index ) 
        {
            var offsetMin =$("p:first-child").offset().top;
            var offsetMax =$("p:last-child").offset().top;
            if($(this).offset().top==offsetMax)
            {                   
                $(this).css("margin-bottom","0px");
            }
            else if($(this).offset().top==offsetMin)
            {
                $(this).css("margin-top","0px");
            }               
        });
    });
</script>
```